# Winform validate label text length

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have a label that is updating automatically based on other inputs. This label can only be 50 characters long. The following code is working when the apply button is clecked, butI want to check the length when the label is changed, so not just when clicking apply on the form. How should I do this?

```
        private void labelDescription_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (labelDescription.Text.Count() > 50)
            {
                //e.Cancel = true;
                errorProvider.SetError(labelDescription, "Please review your description and shorten to a maximum of 50 characters.");
            }
            else
            {
                //e.Cancel = false;
                errorProvider.SetError(labelDescription, null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: a label is usually used to _diplay_ something. you should do your input validation on whatever element the user uses to _input_ data. that being said, i recommend [reading the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label?view=net-5.0) - labels have an [`OntextChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.onTextchanged?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Label_OnTextChanged_System_EventArgs_)-event.

Comment: I understand, but my label is to show the concatenation of several user inputs. These inputs combined can be no longer than 50 characters.

Comment: It's not necessary to use the Validated / Validating events, you can set the same condition in the TextChanged event.

Comment: @Jimi, I did just that. I thought I needed the CancelEventArgs as well, but I works without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following linked to the TextChanged event:

```
private void labelDescription_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int noCharacters = labelDescription.Text.Count();

            if (noCharacters > 50)
            {
                errorProvider.SetError(labelDescription, "Please review your description and shorten to a maximum of 50 characters.");
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider.SetError(labelDescription, null);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `labelDescription.Text.Length`